# Listing elements of $G / H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given $G = \langle x : x^{12} = e \rangle$ and $H = \langle x^3 \rangle$, I am asked to list the elements of $G / H$.

I am completely new to quotient groups and I do not yet completely understand everything from my class lecture. How do I go about in my first step? All I know so far is that $G / H$ denotes the set containing all right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, $G$ is generated by a single element, $x$, so $G$ can have no other elements than powers of $x$, concretely, it has
$$G\ =\ \{e,x,x^2,x^3,\dots,x^{11}\}$$
and satisfies $x^{12}=e$. Now, the subgroup $H$ is generated by $x^3$, it contains all its powers, so
$$H\ =\ \{e,x^3,x^6,x^9\}\,.$$
And, the right coset $Hg$ for an arbitrary element $g=x^k\in G$ is the set
$$Hx^k\ =\ \{x^k,\ x^{k+3},\ x^{k+6},\ x^{k+9}\}\,.$$
where the exponents are meant modulo $12\ $ (because $x^{12}=e$).

All in all, we have *three* cosets at all, so $|\,G/H\,|\,=\,3$, namely $\ H,\ Hx$ and $Hx^2$, as $Hx^3=\{x^3,x^6,x^9,x^{12}\}=H$ already.

Actually, now $H$ is also a *normal* subgroup, thus $G/H$ *is a group*, and it will be isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $3$ (i.e. to $\langle y\,:\,y^3=e\rangle$).

Comment: "And, the right coset '$gH$' " -- The right coset should be "$Hg$", not "$gH$"?

Comment: yes, yes, thanks.

Comment: @glacier: As $G$ is cyclic and so abelian, right and left cosets coincide. One should dispense with the qualification and simply speak of "the coset $gH$" in such cases, no?

Answer (score 1):

Claim: $G/H=\{H,Hx,Hx^2 \}$

why? what about $Hx^5$? notice that $H$ includes all elements of $G$ in the form $x^n$ such that $n\equiv0 \mod 3$. That is why $Hx^5=Hx^2=Hx^8=Hx^{11}$. That is why it is enough to write one of them.

With same reasoning you can see that $H=Hx^3=Hx^6=Hx^9$. (you can see that when power of $x$ are equivalent in mod $3$ they represent same right coset.)

Since in mod $3$ we have $\{0,1,2\}$, these elements $Hx^0,Hx,Hx^2$ are all elements of $G/H$